# python wmm2020 module importing error, what is the issue?

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I have successfully installed the package "wmm2020" in python but this error occurs when I attempt to import the module using pycharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\~\Python\Python38\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-3fd4733928d5>", line 1, in <module>
    import wmm2020
  File "C:\~\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\~\Python\Python38\site-packages\wmm2020\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import wmm, wmm_point
  File "C:\~\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\~\Python\Python38\site-packages\wmm2020\base.py", line 16, in <module>
    build()
  File "C:\~\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\wmm2020\build.py", line 20, in build
    raise FileNotFoundError("CMake not available")
FileNotFoundError: CMake not available
```

I have also installed the "cmake" module but the same error persists.
What is the issue here?

Comment: It does clearly state that CMake is not installed, make sure is installed and also compiler too because the this package requires a CMake.

Comment: I have CMake installed but still getting the same error, what compiler do you mean? and How do I install the compiler?